# Groovy: Parsing registry value

Tags: string, groovy, split, registry

I have just started writing my first Groovy script, in which I want to read the value of a string from the Windows registry and print the last part of what is returned, to the screen.

This is what I have:

```
group = Runtime.getRuntime().exec('reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\App\\UDF1 -v PatchRebootGroup');
System.out.println "patchRebootGroup=" + group;
```

The output of the reg command looks like this:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\App\UDF1
>
> PatchRebootGroup    REG_SZ    Group1

The question is, "How do I print out just 'patchRebootGroup=Group1'?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I ended up using:

```
String output = 'reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\App\\UDF1 -v PatchRebootGroup'.execute().text
String group = output.tokenize(' ')[-1]
println 'DesiredPatchRebootGroup=' + group
return 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming process you are trying to execute generates following output:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\App\UDF1
>
> PatchRebootGroup REG_SZ Group1

you can firstly split input String by `\n`, take the last line, split it by single space and read first and the last part. Something like this:

```
def process = Runtime.runtime.exec('reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\App\\UDF1 -v PatchRebootGroup')

def parts = process.text.split('\n')[1].split(" ")

def output = "${parts[0]}=${parts[2]}"

println output
```

#### Output

```
PatchRebootGroup=Group1
```

You can also try following way to initialize `Process` object:

```
def process = ['reg', 'query', 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\App\\UDF1', '-v', 'PatchRebootGroup'].execute()
```

Comment: Sorry it isn't clear. The output is two lines, not three. So I changed "...`split('\n')[2]`..." to "...`split('\n')[1]`...". But I am seeing the following

Comment: No signature of method: java.lang.ProcessImpl.split() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: []Possible solutions: split(groovy.lang.Closure), wait(), wait(long), sprintf(java.lang.String, [Ljava.lang.Object;), print(java.lang.Object), getAt(java.lang.String)
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.lang.ProcessImpl.split() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: []Possible solutions: split(groovy.lang.Closure), wait(), wait(long), sprintf(java.lang.String, [Ljava.lang.Object;), print(java.lang.Object), getAt(java.lang.String)

Comment: @StackExchangeGuy Try updated example. Exception was thrown, because `split` method was not called on `String` object - my example was simplified to a String input.

Comment: On Reddit, I found a slightly different way of running the 'reg query' command. Thanks for the help.